# How to Ignore Attributes with No Value and Ignore Tags with Specific Class with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to only print the `upc` value of all the sections inside the `results` class section that have a value to the attribute `upc` and also don't contain the class `EAN`.

```html
<div class="results">
  <div upc="1284665">This one</div>
  <div upc="8432651">This one</div>
  <div upc>Not this one</div>
  <div upc="1384268" class="EAN">Not this one too</div>
</div>
```

Desired Output:

```
1284665
8432651
```

This is the code I have now but it includes all sections inside the `results` class section.

```py
html = '''<div class="results">
  <div upc="1284665">This one</div>
  <div upc="8432651">This one</div>
  <div upc>Not this one</div>
  <div upc="1384268" class="EAN">Not this one too</div>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for section in soup.select_one('.results'):
    print(section)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using BeautifulSoup 4.7+
This is pretty easy with CSS selectors:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="results">
  <div upc="1284665">This one</div>
  <div upc="8432651">This one</div>
  <div upc>Not this one</div>
  <div upc="1384268" class="EAN">Not this one too</div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for section in soup.select('.results div[upc]:not([upc=""], .EAN)'):
    print(section['upc'])
```

Output

```
1284665
8432651
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly! What should I add to the `for` loop line of code to make it select all the values of the `upc` attributes that followed the criteria instead of having to print each `upc` value in the next line?

Comment: Can you clarify?  You want to print all the values on the same line? If so, you basically have to extract the info from each element and format it how you like. Something like this should work `print(' '.join([section['upc'] for section in soup.select('.results div[upc]:not([upc=""], .EAN)')]))`.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I want to add the values to a list. I guess this will do it?: `values = [section['upc'] for section in soup.select('.results div[upc]:not([upc=""], .EAN)')]`

Comment: Yup, that'll do nicely. There's no way to automatically return the attribute. You can target the element, but you still have to extract the attribute value.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
for div in soup.find_all("div"):
    if div.get("upc") and "EAN" not in div.get("class", default=[]):
        print(div.get("upc"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with xpaths and navigating trees, you can try using lxml.

```
import lxml
from lxml import html

html_content = '''<div class="results">
  <div upc="1284665">This one</div>
  <div upc="8432651">This one</div>
  <div upc>Not this one</div>
  <div upc="1384268" class="EAN">Not this one too</div>
</div>'''
tree = html.fromstring(html_content)
Items = tree.xpath("//div/div[not(contains(@class,'EAN'))]") 


for item in Items:
    if(item.attrib['upc']!=None):
        print(item.attrib['upc'])
```